# .NET PrintTicket Settings C#

Tags: c#, .net, printing, xps, xpsdocument

I need to print documents in a .NET (C#) microservice. The situation is that some pages of the document need to be stapled, some need to be printed duplex, and others need to be monochrome. I have already found documentation on XPS print jobs, the PrintTicket class, and more. However, I cannot figure out how to write an XPS document that works with print settings to do things like "staple pages 1-6, print pages 7-9 in monochrome," and so on. I need to write these job attributes into a single print request. The [descriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.printing?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) I found haven't helped me either. I'm trying to create a new XPS file with print tickets for each [FixedPage](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.fixedpage?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) and send it to the print queue via Printqueue.AddJob. I have a lot of code samples, but I don't know which one I can post here for example. My print jobs work with a print ticket, but only for the whole document.

Perhaps you know where I can find an answer? Or you have experience and can help me with it in the comments? It should work without user interaction (console application). Thanks!